# What does the phrase "juggling panels in real time" mean here?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, phrases

Here is a sentence from a puzzle game's description:

> In the game, time is far from linear, but for successfully completing
>   some puzzles you need to **juggle panels in real time**.

I know the lexical meanings of the words ["juggle"](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/juggle) and ["real time"](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/real%20time), but cannot make sense of the said phrase. How does the phrase connect to the concept of the non-linear time here?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like while most of the game isn't time-sensitive, some mini-games require you to **juggle** (the first transitive definition at your link) or in this context **switch** or **toggle** between different panels/pages **under a time limit.**